# MySQL: Alter Statement causes Table Lock after finish

Tags: mysql

I add a column to a INNODB table with 5.6GB data (200k rows), 50 columns and 6 indexes.
The statement took 2 minutes to execute and the new column shows up in the *SHOW CREATE TABLE* command.

After some minutes (or perhaps immediately) all INSERTS statements keeps in state *sending data* according to the processlist and the opened table counter increases rapidly. The server load went crazy too.

I couldn't figure out which process locks the table nor do I have any explanation for this. In the end I just restarted the MySQL Server (5.5) and everything works fine.

Could a FLUSH (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) helps in this situation? Are there some settings wrong? I mostly have the default values.

Comment: i guess the problem is with the indexes, after the insert statement it might be too much time to update the new indexes, they might be fragmented or too big, alternatively you can check the locks on the table: show open tables like
(or do you have triggers on the table?)

Comment: I'm with you that the index update may is a problem. There is a Before Insert and a Before UpdateTrigger on this table. Can this be a problem?

Comment: trigger also can cause locks in the logic, here you can find more resources how to find transaction locks for example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html

Comment: You say "table lock", but do you have evidence there was actually a table lock?  Or could it have been a severe slowdown?  What version of 5.5?